# How to split a 7zip file into several smaller files on a Mac

Tags: macos, compression, 7zip

I have a 7zip file that I need to split into several smaller files so that I can put it on a FAT32 flash drive. However, unzipping it requires more space than I currently have. How can I split the 7zip file into several smaller files so that I can later unzip them on another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html) command to partition the file bytewise

```
split -b bytesize xyz.7z
```

To merge, simply run:

```
cat *
```

on all the pieces.

Comment: How would you combine the files using Windows CMD?

Comment: Use `type` instead: https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat